# "There exists $e_0(S)$ such that the shortest nonperipheral curve on $(S, x)$ has extremal length at most $e_0$

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, hyperbolic-geometry

I was reading the paper by Masur-Minsky ([Geometry of the Complex of Curves I: Hyperbolicity](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/9804098)) where they show the curve complex $C(S)$ to be $\delta$-hyperbolic. There given a surface $S$ with conformal structure $x$, they define the extremal length of  $Ext_{x}(\alpha)$ of a curve $\alpha$ to be the reciprocal of the modulus of the largest annulus conformal embedded into $S$.

I wanted to understand a statement they give in Lemma 2.4, in the title and repeated below here:

*"There exists $e_0(S)$ such that the shortest nonperipheral curve on $(S, x)$ has extremal length
at most $e_0$."*

I worry that this likely obvious. They make a comment that hyperbolic length could be used as well and I've heard of upper bounds for the lengths of systoles on closed surfaces. I think I could use this as one way to believe the result but that might be overkill.

Comment: One way to prove this is to use the "thick-thin decomposition" of the moduli space. In the thick part, the length of the shortest geodesic is bounded by compactness. In the thin part, every hyperbolic surface contains a short (in the hyperbolic sense) geodesic, say, shorter than $\mu/2$, half of the Margulis constant of $H^2$. Such geodesics admit embedded collars of some fixed width (again, given by $\mu/2$). Then you can simply estimate the conformal modulus  of such a collar from below by a direct computation. This gives you a uniform upper bound on the extremal length of this geodesic.

Comment: @Misha Thanks this is very helpful. When referring to the "thick-thin decomposition" of moduli space, is this the same thing as the Mumford compactness criterion, (which says (cf Farb-Margalit Ch 12), the set of hyperbolic surfaces that have shortest curve of length at least $\epsilon$ is compact)?

Comment: Yes, that's right.